# Utilizando laços com PDO em PHP

Tags: php, array, pdo, while

Estou tentando criar um laço com PDO aonde eu possa escolher o campo desejado para posicioná-lo na página. Porém o código que eu estou usando está trazendo todos os campos de uma só vez.

Meu código está assim:

```
include("libraries/conn.php");
$sql = "SELECT 
   content.id_content, 
   content.img, 
   content.titulo, 
   povos.pv, 
   cat.categoria, 
   content.inicio, 
   content.fim, 
   content.content, 
   regiao.reg, 
   regiao.wmap
FROM cat 
INNER JOIN regiao 
INNER JOIN povos 
INNER JOIN content ON povos.id_povos = content.civ 
AND regiao.id_regiao = povos.regiao 
AND cat.id_cat = content.clas
ORDER BY rand()";

$result = $PDO->query( $sql );
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r( $rows );
```

O resultado está vindo assim:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_content] => 31 [img] => paleozoica.jpg [titulo] => Era Paleozoica [pv] => Indefinido [categoria] => Arquitetura e Habitação [inicio] => -550000000 [fim] => -250000000 [content] => A era Paleozoica prevaleceu de 550 a 250 milhÃµes de anos atrÃ¡s. Nesse perÃ­odo a superfÃ­cie terrestre passou por grandes transformaÃ§Ãµes, entre eles estÃ£o o surgimento de conjuntos montanhosos como os Alpes Escandinavos (Europa). Essa era geolÃ³gica tambÃ©m se caracteriza mpela ocorrÃªncia de rochas sedimentares e metamÃ³rficas, formaÃ§Ã£o de grandes florestas, glaciaÃ§Ãµes, surgimento dos primeiros insetos e rÃ©pteis. [reg] => Mundo [wmap] => mundo.jpg )

Comment: Trouxe todas as colunas que você selecionou. Qual seria o resultado que esperava obter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe que o array `$rows` possue uma chave `0` com o valor sendo um outro array:

```
Array ( [0] => 
    Array ( 
        [id_content] => 31 
        [img] => paleozoica.jpg 
        [titulo] => Era Paleozoica 
        [pv] => Indefinido 
        ...
```

Então para filtrar o resultado, para cada chave, você tem um array com os dados, ou seja, temos um laço `foreach()` ai, para cada `$rows` vamos separar sua chave e o array com os valores que você precisa:

```
foreach ($rows as $key => $eachRow) {
    echo $eachRow['id_content'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $eachRow['img'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $eachRow['titulo'];
}
```

Como você usou a constante `FETCH_ASSOC` para trazer os resultados, o array `$rows` tem como conteúdo um outro array, assim `$eachRow['id_content']`, `$eachRow['img']`, etc, mas se fosse utilizado `FETCH_OBJ`, por exemplo, o array `$rows` teria um objeto como conteúdo, e poderia ser expressado dentro do laço `foreach()` assim `$eachRow->id_content`, `$eachRow->img`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Para acessar alguma informação dentro da variável `$rows`, faça desta forma:

```
$rows->titulo
$rows->categoria
$rows->inicio
$rows->fim
...
```

Desta forma poderá acessar os registros dentro do array e posicioná-los onde gostaria em qualquer parte da página, sendo que eles estejam dentro do laço.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Rhuan, porém ainda não estou conseguindo o efeito desejado. Meu código ficou assim: 
print_r( $rows->titulo );  e o navegador está retornando a mensagem "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\n_archaeus\index.php on line 14"